# Unable to view Accounts in Salesforce1

Tags: mobile, salesforce1-app, ios

In the Salesforce1 mobile app (iOs) when I select Accounts I receive the following message "Oops, we ran into some unexpected error. Sorry..."  I am able to view all other objects just fine.  If I go to a Contact record, I can view the related Account record by clicking on the link, but I can't do a search directly on the Account tab.

Has anyone else experienced this issue with Salesforce1?

Comment: This might need salesforce support, since it is most likely related to some special code (Visualforce?) running amok.

Comment: did you change the account label or do you have any other tabs labeled as such ? We think we found a bug about duplicate label names.